# jQuery clone/append creating multiple duplicates

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to duplicate a div and append it on top of it's clone.  Unfortunately, it seems to be creating extra duplicates.  What's going on?

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QEN5N/

Comment: You might also want to look into using **.prependTo()**. You're currently using .appendTo() which adds something to the end of an element, but prependTo will "append it on top" (http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

live will apply it to all the new ones with that class to, so your getting the mouse overs on your created elements and then it's making another and so on.

remove the `searchResultItem` class from your clone by changing it to be like so.

```
elem.addClass('created').removeClass('searchResultItem');
```

or:

disclude the created ones. like so:

```
$('.searchResultItem:not(.created)')
```

either works :)

Comment: Figured it out right as you posted. But that was a perfect answer.  Thanks!  Here's the updated fiddle for posterity: http://jsfiddle.net/QEN5N/3/

Comment: Frédéric is correct, I believe. But the solution still stands.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/QEN5N/2/

Important changes:

```
$('.searchResultItem:not(.clone)').live({ ...

elem.addClass('clone');
```

`.live` binds mouseover also to cloned elements.

PS `.live` is deprecated use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're cloning the entire div, including the class "searchResultItem". So it's cloning the behavior on that item as well. Just add in a line to your code above your elem.css:

```
elem.attr('class', 'searchResultItemClone');
```

And actually, then you could take out all the javascript that's applying your styles and just add the searchResultItemClone into your stylesheet.